# Answer doesn't answer question but answers title and Google

Tags: discussion, answers, search, title

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033098/215380) answers the *title* of its question, but misses out a key request in the body of the question.

It also answers [a basic Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linq+merge+lists), and I suspect this is why it is steadily accumulating upvotes - people search Google, find a link that matches their question, find an answer that answers their question, and upvote it without considering that it doesn't answer the question it is attached to.

The result is a highly voted answer that doesn't answer the question it is attached to. It's not a *bad* answer, it just doesn't answer its question.

There are answers that *do* answer the question, but they don't have a hope against this answer, and the asker is long gone so can't accept whichever one worked for him to bring it to the top.

What can we do here?

- Edit the title of the question in the hope it stops showing up in Google?
- Edit the question to match the answer?
- Ask the answerer to edit or delete their answer?
- Edit the answer for them?
- Accept that a visible and upvoted answer isn't actually an answer to its question?

Comment: "Ask the answerer to edit or delete their answer?" - that sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @JanDvorak Because they're unlikely to want to?

Comment: Because you'd lose a good answer that way

Comment: @JanDvorak Is it a good answer if it doesn't answer the question? They could always edit it to keep the good bits and also answer the question, but if the good bits are irrelevant to the question, is it really a good answer?

Comment: It apparently helps people, and people can find it. so...

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution to these sort of problems is a feature that would allow a moderator to choose a best answer for the original user asking the question. That may already exist, I don't know.

Comment: @CameronLattz That's risky... Mods can do this on the MSDN forums and I see quite a few posts saying "Why was this marked as an answer for me, it doesn't help at all".

Comment: Answers are not only for the OP, they are for all future users. Even if it doesn't address the entire question, it adds value as an answer. It shouldn't be removed or edited. We can post another answer with the missing info, if we want.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce I thought it might well apply to questions on other SE sites.

Comment: @Rawling It certainly would be dangerous, and if it existed it should be used very sparingly. It's probably a rare enough problem to not really warrant the extra feature.